# Determining first element of an AR1 model

Tags: time-series, vector-auto-regression

I have an AR1 process of the well-known form:

$y(t) = a*y(t-1) + e(t)$

And, in any computational software the elements of the time-series $y$ will be stored in a vector.

Now, how can I calculate $y(1)$ when $y(1-1=0)$ does not exist?

Comment: What is this distinction you are making between $y$ and $Y?$

Comment: The "defining equation" of an AR-1 is $Y_t = a Y_{t-1} +\epsilon_t.$ Just one $Y.$ As in, the next value of $Y$ depends on the previous value (and also on some new noise). There is not some other precomputed thing called $y.$

Comment: Question revised

Comment: So in practice the first element of the autoregressive model of the time-series has the same value as the first element of the time-series?

Comment: what is 'the first element of the autoregressive model of the time series'?

Comment: $y(t=0)$. There is no $y(t=-1)$, meaning there are no previous values of $y$ to feed into the AR1 defining equation.

Comment: Yeah, but what *is* $y(0)$? Anyway, I wrote an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72792/discussion-between-fabio-capezzuoli-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You must specify, as part of the process, an initial condition, i.e. a value for $Y_0.$ It's possible in theory (and in practice to some extent) for this to be random, i.e. drawn from some distribution.

If $|a|<1,$ the process is stationary and there is a stationary distribution for $Y.$ A natural choice might be to draw $Y_0$ from this stationary distribution (this might be familiar if you've studied Markov chains). This is similar to imagining the process 'has always been running'.

For practical simulation, when it might be impossible or too much trouble to produce variates from the stationary distribution, a typical technique that works is 'burn-off' (which some consider as wasteful as it sounds). You select some initial $Y_0$... it doesn't matter much what you pick as long is it's not too atypical relative to the stationary distribution. Then you run the simulation for some decent number of time steps till you're confident the system has evolved to its stationary state, then you start the process again "for real" with the final value from the burn-off run as your new initial $Y_0.$

It's also not necessarily the case that you *want* the initial value to be from the stationary distribution, it depends what your purposes are.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hoping for.What I have is a time-series of some real-world measurements, so I may as well take $Y0$ as the value of the first datum in the series.

Comment: @FabioCapezzuoli Oh, well then I guess you want to *fit* an AR-1 model, which is a different question entirely. (Also might explain your confusion with the two different series.)

Comment: I have a time-series of values of a variable, and I would like to fit an AR1 model to this series, because I need to use this function as input of other elaborations.